# Android : inflate a custom layout when using Firebase Vision API

Tags: android, firebase, graphics, barcode, arcore

I'm using **firebase ml vision** API for **barcode live detection**.
I want to **inflate a custom view** and draw it on to of the detected barcode instead of the rectangle shape demonstrated in the demo.

Does anyone have any suggestion of how to implement such thing ?

I thought of using the Firebase Vision API with ARCore to show my custom view but the ARCore needs at least android API 24.